# Handle hide/unhide rows based on Worksheet_Change event

Tags: excel, vba

```
If Range("B5") = ("Consult Fee 549") Or Range("B6") = "Consult Fee 632" Then
    Range("A1").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Range("A1").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

The above is running fine.

If I change "Consult Fee 549" to a variable defined in Name Manager: Consult_Fee_1

```
If Range("B5") = ("Consult_Fee_1") Or Range("B6") = "Consult_Fee_2" Then
```

Then it will not work for ("B5") = ("Consult_Fee_1") but is still working for ("B6") = "Consult_Fee_2"

Is it not possible to use variables together wit Range()?

Comment: What happens if you remove the parenthesis from this? `("Consult_Fee_1")`

Comment: Insert the defined name in the Range object like this Range("defined_name")

Comment: None of the above suggestions are working, any other suggestions?

Comment: I found a solution, since Consult_Fee_1 is defined in Sheet2, I have write following: If Range("B5") = Sheet2.Range("Consult_Fee_1") then it is workinh. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Change: Show Row When At Least One String Pair Is Equal

- It is assumed that `Consult_Fee_1` and `Consult_Fee_2` are names of workbook scope referring to single cells located anywhere in the workbook.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const DST_TARGET_CELLS As String = "B5,B6"
    Const DST_HIDE_SHOW_ROW As Long = 1
    Dim CompareNames():
    CompareNames = VBA.Array("Consult_Fee_1", "Consult_Fee_2")
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Me.Range(DST_TARGET_CELLS)
    If Intersect(drg, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no cells changed
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Me.Parent ' or Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sCell As Range, dCell As Range, n As Long
    Dim sStr As String, dStr As String, IsEqual As Boolean
    
    For n = 1 To drg.Cells.Count
        
        Set sCell = wb.Names(CompareNames(n - 1)).RefersToRange
        Set dCell = drg.Cells(n)
        
        sStr = CStr(sCell.Value)
        dStr = CStr(dCell.Value)
        
        If StrComp(sStr, dStr, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' is equal
            IsEqual = True
            Exit For ' no need to loop anymore
        End If
    
    Next n
    
    With Me.Rows(DST_HIDE_SHOW_ROW)
        If .Hidden = IsEqual Then .Hidden = Not IsEqual
        ' i.e.
'        If IsEqual Then
'            ' No need to unhide if it's already not hidden.
'            If .Hidden Then .Hidden = False
'        Else
'            ' No need to hide if it's already hidden.
'            If Not .Hidden Then .Hidden = True
'        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full review rather a specific one to your question.

There is a difference between a Defined Name in Excel and a variable.

Defined name is a range identifier on the sheet at the top left corner, or in the Formulas tab Name Manager. That can be used something like this

```vb
var1 = Range("defined_name1")
```

A variable also can be used to implement a parameter to a Range object something like this

```
defined_name2 = "A1:B6"
var1 = Range(defined_name2)
```

But these two identifiers are not the same. The first is an Excel parameter, which can be accessed in VBA e.g. via the workbook Names(i).Value property.

The second one is a VBA Variant variable, which is used in an expression.